# prevent rails server from launching if file doesnt exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services

I have `aws.yml`

```
development:
  asset_host: 'abcd1234efgh@cloudfront.net'
```

I created `assets.rb`

```
AWS_CONFIG = Rails.application.config_for(:aws)
unless (AWS_CONFIG.nil? || AWS_CONFIG['asset_host'].nil?)
  Rails.application.config.asset_host = AWS_CONFIG['asset_host']
end
```

I am trying to implement the logic if `aws.yml` not exists then it should completely blow up and prevent the rails server from launching. Any idea how could i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can just raise an error based on your condition.

```
raise "Essential file doesn't exist"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put this code in initializers and check

```
AWS_CONFIG = Rails.application.config_for(:aws)
unless (AWS_CONFIG.nil? || AWS_CONFIG['asset_host'].nil?)
  raise "AWS file doesn't exist"
end
```

And also check with

```
unless File.exist? File.expand_path "aws.ics" #proper path of your file
   raise "AWS file doesn't exist"
end
```